# cannot be resolved to a variable in Java for base class

Tags: java

I am new to java and creating a small program to clear with the basic fundamentals of the core java. I am creating a program of employee basic information and salary count. But when I am trying to access the parent variable so that I can use the variable and calculate the salary of the employee, but I am getting an error message that **"empSalaryobj cannot be resolved to a variable"**.

Below is my Java Code,

```
class varEmployee {
    int empId;
    String empName;
    final String empCompany = "Tata Consultancy Services";
    int empSalary;
    String empGender;
    int empAge;
    String empNationality;
}

class setEmployee extends varEmployee{


    setEmployee(){

    }

    setEmployee(int empId){
        this.empId=empId;
        switch(empId){  

            case 1: 
                empName = "Aditya Batra";
                empSalary = 10000;
                empGender = "Male";
                empAge = 26;
                empNationality = "Indian";
            break;  

            case 2: 
                empName = "Vishal Sharma";
                empSalary = 20500;
                empGender = "Male";
                empAge = 26;
                empNationality = "Australia";
            break;  

            case 3: 
                empName = "Ashish Tiwari";
                empSalary = 30000;
                empGender = "Male";
                empAge = 28;
                empNationality = "Indian";
            break;  

            case 4: 
                empName = "Mona Lisha";
                empSalary = 40000;
                empGender = "Female";
                empAge = 24;
                empNationality = "Oganda";
            break;

            default:

                System.out.println("Invalid Employee ID");
        }  
    }

}

class getEmployee extends setEmployee {

    getEmployee(){

    }

    getEmployee(setEmployee obj){

        int empIdobj = obj.empId;
        String empNameobj = obj.empName;
        int empSalaryobj = obj.empSalary;
        String empGenderobj = obj.empGender;
        int empAgeobj = obj.empAge;
        String empNationalityobj = obj.empNationality;

        System.out.println("Employee Id: "+empIdobj+"\nName: "
                           +empNameobj+"\nSalary: "+empSalaryobj
                           +"\nGender: "+empGenderobj+"\nAge: "
                           +empAgeobj+"\nNationality: "+empNationalityobj
                           +"\nCompany Name: "+empCompany);

    }
}

class getEmployeeSalary extends getEmployee {

    int empSalaryCaculation = empSalaryobj;

    getEmployeeSalary(int empLeaves){
        float empSal = (empSalaryCaculation/30)*(30-empLeaves);
        System.out.println("Salary after leave deduction: "+empSal);
    }

}

public class Employee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setEmployee setobj=new setEmployee(1);
        getEmployee getobj=new getEmployee(setobj);
        getEmployeeSalary salobj=new getEmployeeSalary(5);
    }

}
```

Can someone please help me out. I also want to know why this error message for.

Comment: I would first work on naming conventions and fixing those class names ha.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. The way I have written is not the correct way? I am learning so don't have much idea about that.

Comment: `empSalaryob` is a local variable in `getEmployee` method in `getEmployee` class, so it cannot be accessed else where, also the class names seem weird, getter and setter classes?

Comment: suppose the question and approach you have followed is not good.

Comment: In your `getEmployee(setEmployee obj)` move the variables declaration to top

Comment: Hi @ADITYABATRA please follow naming Convention by reading this oracle article http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html also get and set identifier is only used in a method and not in a class

Comment: @ADITYABATRA you are learning the wrong way about using the get and set in an identifier.. I suggest you read the java tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ because you are really learning the wrong way this will be critical when you apply to a job as a software developer

Comment: Hi @abcOfJava, Thank you! I really need to work on this. Thank you for the articles. I will go through with this for sure.

Comment: I have declared the variable on the top, but it is not getting the value from its parent class. It gives 'Salary after leave deduction: 0.0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have a constructor for your getEmployeeSalary class

```
getEmployeeSalary(int empLeaves,getEmployee employee)
{
 float empSal = (employee.empSalaryobj/30)*(30-empLeaves);
        System.out.println("Salary after leave deduction: "+empSal);
}
```

and you need not to have `int empSalaryCaculation = empSalaryobj;` because you directly implement it inside the getEmployeeSalary constructor

also you need to make the empSalary a datafields of class getEmployee

```
public class getEmployee extends varEmployee
{
    public int empSalaryobj;



}
```

here I use Eric Allman indention style because it is better than K&R style in any debate

Comment: Hello @abcOfJava,
I have implemented the solution and its working now.
I have checked and learned many things from the article you have provided. I really need to work hard. Thank You!

Comment: @ADITYABATRA no problem glad I could help have a fun journey on coding in java specially when you finally meet the swing components

Answer (score 1):

`empSalaryobj` is a local variable defined in the constructor of `getEmployee`. It is not a field of any of the parent classes of `getEmployeeSalary`, due to which it can't be accessed in the constructor of `getEmployeeSalary`.